# How to send post request to iotdata service with authorization from a node js lambda function

Tags: node.js, rest, lambda, amazon-iam, aws-iot

I have the following post request that works in insomnia, but am not sure how to send it in node js lambda function, specifically I don't know how to do the authorization.

Here is my setup in insomnia

post request

`https://obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow`

json

```
{
    "state" :{
        "desired":{
            "on": true
        }
    }
}
```

auth

[image: auth]

What I would do, but don't know where to put the auth, I am also not sure where to put the body of the message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const https = require('https')

const data = JSON.stringify({
  todo: 'Buy the milk'
})

const options = {
  hostname: 'https://obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Content-Length': data.length
  }
}

const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)

  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})

req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})

req.write(data)
req.end()
```

UPDATE: I have tried the following but it error with no console, is there a way to get the request error

```
var load = JSON.stringify({
      state: {
        desired: {
          on: false,
        },
      },
    });

    request(
      aws4.sign(
        {
          hostname: "https://obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
          service: "iotdata",
          region: "us-east-1",
          method: "POST",
          path: "/things/esp8266_7F3B95/shadow",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0",
          },
          body: load,
        },
        {
          secretAccessKey: "obsf/obsf/x5Hpej0I",
          accessKeyId: "obsf",
        }
      )
    );
```

UPDATE: I am getting the following error and a 403

```
etaddrinfo ENOTFOUND https://obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to change this from

`hostname: 'https://obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',`

to this

`hostname: 'obsf-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',`